# Как сделать multiprocessing для одной функции запущенной несколько раз

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Есть одна функция, её нужно запустить 4 раза с разными данными так, чтобы все эти 4 раза функция запускались одновременно, с максимальной производительностью, а не поочерёдно. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

```
    def func(a1, a2, a3):
        a1 * 200 / 30
        a2 * 200 / 30
        a3 * 200 / 30
        print(a1, a2, a3)


func(32, 34, 54)
func(55, 64, 88)
func(12, 54, 98)
func(11, 23, 35)
```

Comment: Вы считаете, что функция `func` имеет какую-то значительную вычислительную сложность, чтобы её стоило запускать в отдельных потоках?

Comment: Мне только нужно, чтобы эта функция, с четырьмя разными значениями, выполнялась одновременно, а не поочерёдно.

Comment: Я к тому, что если вам нужна максимальная производительность, то она может быть _в данном случае_ достигнута за счет _поочередного запуска задач_, так как накладные расходы на создание нескольких параллельных процессов для лёгких задач могут ухудшить общую производительность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый банальный вариант:

```
import multiprocessing


def func(a1, a2, a3):
    a1 * 200 / 30
    a2 * 200 / 30
    a3 * 200 / 30
    print(a1, a2, a3)


args = ((32, 34, 54), (55, 64, 88), (12, 54, 98), (11, 23, 35))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for arg in args:
        multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=arg).start()
```

Comment: Огромнейшее вам СПАСИБО! Всё работает!  Если не трудно, то можете скинуть мне годную  информацию о этой теме? Ещё раз спасибо Вам!

Comment: @КириллМак
[Многопоточность и Многопроцессорность Python](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6plRXMq5RAAb9gwGqmgAoA-KIr-7CMuz)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку multiprocessing для параллельного запуска функций в Python.

```
import multiprocessing


def print_func(a1, a2, a3):
    a1 * 200 / 30
    a2 * 200 / 30
    a3 * 200 / 30
    print(a1, a2, a3)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    procs = []
    def run_process(a1, a2, a3):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=print_func, args=(a1, a2, a3,))
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()
        return p


    run_process(32, 34, 54)
    run_process(55, 64, 88)
    run_process(12, 54, 98)
    run_process(11, 23, 35)


    # complete the processes
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ! Но человек ниже на него уже дал своё решение. В любом случае, я Ваш ответ тоже рассмотрю. Ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
args = ((32, 34, 54), (55, 64, 88), (12, 54, 98), (11, 23, 35))
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as p:
    p.starmap(func, args)
```